# VBA Subtract two different 3 dimensional Arrays from eachother

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am a totally newbie in Vba and need to solve a specific problem with a macro and vba. I hope, you can help me with this problem!

I try to built a macro which should help me with this steps:

1. I use a "cockpit-file" with which I want to substract all cells from two worksheets with eachother. I get the worksheets from two different workbooks. ;-) As an example: I want to subtract the cell F11 (Workbook1.Worksheet1) from F11 (Workbook2.Worksheet1), than F12 (workboosk1.worksheet1) from F12 (Workbook2.Worksheet1), [...] J34 (Wb1.ws1.) from J34(Wb2.ws.1)
2. I want to change and select the files. Therefore I need window in which one I can select the specific files.
3. To avoid errors the math should be done via Arrays in vba. And the new Value should be added in one of the workbooks

I tried to use a Loop to solve the problem with the math but it doesn't work. When I come to the subtractionformula I get the runtime error 13.

Hope you can help me! Sorry for my bad english

Thats my code

```
Sub Makro4()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Variabledef
    Dim i As Long 'Index
    Dim j As Long 'Index
    Dim k As Long 'Index
    Dim ArrayA As Variant 'Array
    Dim ArrayB As Variant 'Array
    Dim ArrayC As Variant 'Array
    Dim MyFile1 As String 'Workbookname
    Dim MyFile2 As String 'Workbookname
    Dim wb1 As String 'Workbookname
    Dim wb2 As String 'Workbookname
    Dim WS_Count1 As Integer 'Count Worksheets
    Dim WS_Count2 As Integer 'Count Worksheets
    Dim arrays1 As String 'Dimension
    Dim arrays2 As String 'Dimension


    'Change the actual path

    ChDrive "O:\"
    ChDir "O:[.......]\VBA"


    'Selection first File

    MyFile1 = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFile1, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ArrayA = Workbooks(wb1).Worksheets("01").Range("F11:GL46").Value
    WS_Count1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


    'Selection second File

    MyFile2 = Application.GetOpenFilename
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFile2, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ArrayB = Workbooks(wb2).Worksheets("01").Range("F11:GL46").Value
    WS_Count2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count



' Calculation of the math - Runtime Error 13

    For k = 1 To WS_Count1
        For i = LBound(ArrayA, 1) To UBound(ArrayA, 1)
            For j = LBound(ArrayA, 2) To UBound(ArrayA, 2)
                ArrayC(i, j) = ArrayA(i, j) - ArrayB(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

        Worksheets("k").Range("F11:GL34").Value = ArrayC

    Next k


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?
Is it correct that you want to apply an array which originally comes from  `Range("F11:GL46")` to `Range("F11:H34")`?

Comment: @HerrDerb sorry, there was a typing error. the new values should be added into the same Range `Range("F11:GL46")`. I get the error in the line  `ArrayC(i,j) = ArrayA(i,j) - ArrayB(i,j)`

Comment: Think the problem is that you have not defined the size of `ArrayC` anywhere.

Comment: "To avoid errors the math should be done via Arrays in vba"
Why?
I'd select the first range and copy to destination, then select second range and do copy, paste special, values, subtract over the first copy

Comment: @HarassedDad thanks for your hint but that's a percept from my mangager..

Comment: I ask him why and he told me, that the advantage of arrays is, that the methode is much faster because it is done in the RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayC` is not initialized yet. It's defined as `Variant`, which means, the type is unknown until something gets assigned to the variable.

With this line `ArrayC(i, j) = ArrayA(i, j) - ArrayB(i, j)` you already assume that `ArrayC` holds an array, which it doesn't yet.

First define `ArrayC` in your head like this `Dim ArrayC()`. this way it's clearly defined as an array. Still without size though.

Now before the line `For k = 1 To WS_Count1`, you set the dimension of your array this way `ReDim ArrayC(UBound(ArrayA,1) ,UBound(ArrayA,2))` This should create an 2D array with the same size as `ArrayA`. 
Now you have a fully initialized array

Now your program should work.

Comment: I changed everything like you told me but the same error still occures. (Runtime Error 13)

Comment: On what line does it occure?

Comment: it occures at the same line `ArrayC(i,j) = ArrayA(i,j) - ArrayB(i,j)` I changed the `Dim ArrayC As Variant ` to `Dim ArrayC() ` and paste the `Redim ArrayC[...] ` infront of the `For k [...] `

Comment: What data do you arrays contain? Numbers?

Comment: Yeah, Numbers. Your code works! There were some `#DIV/0!` in my Data. I integrated `If Not IsError(ArrayA(i, j)) Or Not IsError(ArrayA(i, j)) Then ArrayC(i, j) = ArrayA(i, j) - ArrayB(i, j)` and it seems so like that works

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: so true... this `if Not Is Error [...]` - do you know, if there is also a expression to ignore other things such as words ? I changed the range of my data and there are also words in the sheet which prevent Excel to do the math