# Subtraction of two multidimensional Arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, loops

I have a problem with a selfmade vba-code. The makro should solve the following problem: I use a "cockpitfile" It should load the elemts of two worksheets from two different Excel files into two Arrays. The Elements of these Arrays should be subtracted from each other. I want to get the difference from these two elements. As an example: ArrayElm1(1,1) - ArrayElm2(1,1) = ArrayElm3(1,1), ArrayElm1(1,2) - ArrayElm2(1,2) = ArrayElm3(1,2) etc.

On the first sight the code seems to work but when I check the results with my calculater the difference of the elements is wrong. Maybe there is a problem with the `UBound` because in my `Ubound` is only Array A?

Hope you can help me!

```
Sub Differenz1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Variabledefinition
Dim i As Long 'Index
Dim j As Long 'Index
Dim k As Long 'Index
Dim ArrayA As Variant 'Array
Dim ArrayB As Variant 'Array
Dim ArrayC(71, 25) As Variant  'Array
Dim myFile1 As String 'Workbookname
Dim myFile2 As String 'Workbookname
Dim wb1 As String 'Workbookname
Dim wb2 As String 'Workbookname
Dim WS_Count1 As Integer 'Count Worksheets
Dim WS_Count2 As Integer 'Count Worksheets
Dim arrays1 As String 'Dimension
Dim arrays2 As String 'Dimension


'Change the actual path

ChDrive "O:\"
ChDir "O:..."


myFile1 = Application.GetOpenFilename
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile1, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
wb1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
WS_Count1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count



myFile2 = Application.GetOpenFilename
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFile2, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
wb2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
WS_Count2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count



For k = 1 To WS_Count1

ArrayA = Workbooks(wb1).Worksheets(k).Range("F5:Y75").Value
ArrayB = Workbooks(wb2).Worksheets(k).Range("F5:Y75").Value
    For i = LBound(ArrayA, 1) To UBound(ArrayA, 1)
        For j = LBound(ArrayA, 2) To UBound(ArrayA, 2)
            If Not IsError(ArrayA(i, j)) And Not IsError(ArrayB(i, j)) Then ArrayC(i, j) = ArrayA(i, j) - ArrayB(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k + 1).Range("F5:Y75").Value = ArrayC

Next k


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it right, but the issues was that you didn't reset ArrayC

This code creates new sheets in ThisWorkbook for subtractions, and based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787259/vba-subtract-two-different-3-dimensional-arrays-from-eachother) it checks for errors, and performs the subtractions only if both values are numbers

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Differenz2()
    Const USED_RNG = "F5:Y75"   'Main range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, file1 As String, file2 As String, ws1Count As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, arr3 As Variant

    'ChDrive "O:\":  ChDir "O:..."
    file1 = Application.GetOpenFilename:    If file1 = "False" Then Exit Sub
    file2 = Application.GetOpenFilename:    If file2 = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file1, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file2, ReadOnly:=True)
    ws1Count = wb1.Worksheets.Count
    If ws1Count = wb2.Worksheets.Count Then
        MakeNewWS ws1Count    'Remove this line if ThisWorkbook is properly setup
        For k = 1 To ws1Count
            arr1 = wb1.Worksheets(k).Range(USED_RNG).Value
            arr2 = wb2.Worksheets(k).Range(USED_RNG).Value
            ReDim arr3(1 To 71, 1 To 20)    'reset array, based on USED_RNG ("F5:Y75")
            For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
                For j = LBound(arr1, 2) To UBound(arr1, 2)
                    If Not IsError(arr1(i, j)) And Not IsError(arr2(i, j)) Then
                        If IsNumeric(arr1(i, j)) And IsNumeric(arr2(i, j)) Then
                            arr3(i, j) = arr1(i, j) - arr2(i, j)
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k + 1).Range(USED_RNG) = arr3
        Next
    End If
    wb1.Close False:    wb2.Close False:    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub MakeNewWS(ByVal wsCount As Long)
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Left(ws.Name, 12) = "Subtraction " Then
                If .Count = 1 Then .Add
                ws.Delete
            End If
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        For i = 2 To wsCount + 1
            .Add After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.Count)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(.Count).Name = "Subtraction " & i - 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

You can ignore the `MakeNewWS()` sub if ThisWorkbook contains the proper number of sheets

Also, using arrays does improve performance (significantly)

Comment: This verifies that file 1 has the same number of sheets as file 2, otherwise it doesn't execute. If file 2 can contain more sheets than file 1 (but not less) remove the condition `If ws1Count = wb2.Worksheets.Count Then` (and its corresponding `End If`)

Comment: hello @Paul bica! Sorry for my late answer. Saw your post this morning and the code works perfect! Thank you for helping me and to also add the seconde code plus `wb1.close False`